# How to work around this DataGridView update behavior?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with all text columns read-only and an enabled check box column. The DGV data source is a binding source with its own data source set to a table in a data set. The idea is that the user will click the checkbox on each row that will be further processed. The checkbox is not unbound but part of the database.

However, clicking the checkbox on a row appears to automatically update not just the binding source but the data table *behind* the binding source.

Is this expected behavior? I had expected it to update the binding source, and then I would have to use `BindingSource.EndEdit()` at some point to update the actual data tables in the data set. I have used DGVs before only in read-only mode, never to enter data (use forms for that).

Here is the code behind the submit button.

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // without calling DataGridView.EndEdit() nor BindingSource.EndEdit()
    // this correctly returns updated rows from the data set
    var filtered = timeTrackDataSet.TimeSlips.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<bool>("Included") is true);
    
    // and this updates the database ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    timeSlipsTableAdapter.Update(timeTrackDataSet.TimeSlips);
}
```

I would rather update the data tables in the data set under my control, not automatically. Is there a DGV property I'm missing? Everyone else's problem seems to be that their DGVs *don't* update.

**EDIT:** Removed extraneous Designer code, given that this *is* the expected behavior.

Comment: Yes, that is expected behavior.  Try `timeSlipsBindingSource.SuspendBinding();` and `timeSlipsBindingSource.ResumeBinding();`

Comment: @LarsTech, I will experiment with that.